# Prove convergance of one series by using another

Tags: calculus

**Question**:

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n , \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ are 2 positive series that satisfy:
$\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n} \le \frac {b_{n+1}}{b_n}$

Show that if $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ converges then $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges.

**What I did:**

$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ converges  $\Rightarrow S_{b_n}$ (sequence of sums of $b_n$). is bounded: $m \le S_{b_n} \le M$. The only bound I could think about was $\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n} \le \frac {b_{n+1}}{b_n} \le \frac {max(S_{b_n})}{min(S_{b_n})}$ but it's bigger than 1 from what I understand so I can't use D'Alembert's test.

I prefer hints at first ... Thanks

Comment: This is just applying the ratio test twice.

Comment: On which series/sequence? I mean from what I know, I cant assume that the ratio test works on $b_n$ if the series converges (This conclusion goes only the other way round)

Answer (score 1):

We have $\frac {a_{n+1}}{b_{n+1}} \le \frac {a_{n}}{b_n}$ so the sequence $(\frac {a_{n}}{b_n})$ is decreasing and then
$$\frac {a_{n}}{b_n}\leq \frac {a_{0}}{b_0}=\lambda\quad\forall n\geq0$$
so $0\leq a_n\leq \lambda b_n$ and you can conclude by comparaison.